# Вызвать CMD-команду с помощью Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь выполнить простую CMD-команду с помощью Qt-приложения. Безуспешно. Что я делаю неправильно?

```
QString program = "C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "cd C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin" << "mysqldump -uroot -ppasw database clients > E:/clients.sql";

QProcess myProcess;
myProcess.start(program, arguments);
myProcess.waitForFinished (-1);
```

Comment: Параметр с пробелами нужно заключить в кавычки.

Comment: Для начала стоило бы прочитать, какие аргументы принимает cmd.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустите `cmd /?` и посмотрите какие параметры могут передаваться при запуске, и обратите внимание на ключи `/C` и `/K`.

После этого попробуйте запустить правильную команду из командной строки. На ваше текущее художество cmd ответит непонятно чем, при этом сам cmd.exe останется висеть запущенным процессом.

Варианты решения:
Правильная командная строка:

```
cmd /c "cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin&&mysqldump -uroot -ppasw database clients > E:/clients.sql"
```

Если уж приспичило скармливать команды поштучно, то что-то типа такого

```
QProcess p;
QString cmdlist="cd C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\bin\nmysqldump -uroot -ppasw database clients > E:\\clients.sql\n";
p.start("cmd");
p.write(cmdlist.toUtf8());
p.write("exit\n");
p.waitForFinished(-1);
```

Comment: И не забудьте поместить в кавычки параметры с пробелами! Ну не будет работать `cd C:\Program Files\MySQL` даже в обычной командной строке... Потому что `cd` будет считать, что перейти надо в `C:\Program`...